# How to fix HPA deprecation warning on GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

### Observed output

```
kubectl describe hpa  
Warning: autoscaling/v2beta2 HorizontalPodAutoscaler is deprecated in v1.23+, unavailable in v1.26+; use autoscaling/v2 HorizontalPodAutoscaler
```

### Attempted fix

Specified `autoscaling/v2` in yml file, but warning remains.

```
head -n1 my_hpa.yml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kubectl apply -f my_hpa.yml
kubectl describe hpa  
Warning: autoscaling/v2beta2 HorizontalPodAutoscaler is deprecated in v1.23+, unavailable in v1.26+; use autoscaling/v2 HorizontalPodAutoscaler
```

### Cluster supports v2

```
kubectl api-versions | grep autoscaling/
autoscaling/v1
autoscaling/v2
autoscaling/v2beta1
autoscaling/v2beta2
```

Answer (score 0):

That warning is not related to your yaml configurations.

You should update your kubectl client, somewhat matching kubernetes api server version.

Comment: kubectl client version matches server (both are 1.24) but warning persists